# C# WCF can't change class property

Tags: c#, wcf, object

I am doing some IoT thing with sensors and I'm trying to change temperature values. 
The trouble I have is that I cannot change property which I have in class. I'm using Interface, class Sensors, and class which implements interface. Look the code bellow.
Bellow is class method ChangeTemp(), just for test

```
public string ChangeTemp()
{
    TemperaturaZrak = 12; //property value change - class sensor
    return TemperaturaZrak.ToString();//just for test if really change value
}
```

Interface contract definition

```
[OperationContract]
string changeProperty();
```

Class that implement interface

```
public string changeProperty()
{
    return sr.ChangeTemp(); //web service return new temperature?
}
```

Full class sensors

```
[DataContract(Name ="SmartRoomClass")]
public  class SmartRoomClass
{
    private double t1;
    private double t2;
    [DataMember(Name = "temperaturaZrak")]
    public double TemperaturaZrak //getter,setter
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public SmartRoomClass() //constructor
    {
        TemperaturaZrak = 15;
    }

    public  void CheckTemperature1(double t1, double t2)
    {
        if (TemperaturaZrak >= t1)
        {
            TemperaturaZrak = 26;
        }
        if (TemperaturaZrak <= t2)
        {
            TemperaturaZrak = 22;
        }
    }
}
```

Service

```
namespace vaja_2sua.Services
{
    public class SmartRoom : ISmartRoom
    {
        SmartRoomClass sr = new SmartRoomClass();
        public void checkTemperature(double t1, double t2)
        {
            sr.CheckTemperature1(t1, t2);
        }

        public bool checkTemperature(double temperatura)
        {
            if (temperatura > 40)
                return true;
            else
                return false;
        }

        public  double getAirTemperature()
        {
            return sr.TemperaturaZrak;
        }
    }
}
```

Interface

```
[ServiceContract(Name= "ISmartRoom")]
public interface ISmartRoom
{
    [OperationContract]
    void checkTemperature(double t1, double t2);

    [OperationContract(Name = "GetAirTemperature")]
    double getAirTemperature();
}
```

I can provide more informations if needed.
Greetings.

Comment: Yes, we need more info about your problem. Did you try to call wcf service and it returned the old value? Or did you have another problem? Note that instances of WCF services can be instanced each time service was called. How do you inject example class to your WCF service? Need it save and store some state per each call?

Comment: WCF service return me same value as is in constructor..

Comment: It seems like your setter or getter of TemperaturaZrak works wrong. See full code of the service (I need a constructor) and Sensors class (with property, backfield and other details).

Comment: updated with more code @VadimMartynov

Answer (score 1):

Your behavior is expected because WCF service creates each time if you call it in different sessions. Let's explain your problem step by step.

There are 3 options in WCF service instancing that defines [`InstanceContextMode`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.instancecontextmode(v=vs.110).aspx) enumeration:

- PerCall - new instance of the service will creates per each call.
- PerSession - there is only one instance per each session with its own
  state.
- Single - you will always have the same instance with its
  context.

You can specify WCF service behavior by using [`ServiceBehaviorAttribute`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.servicebehaviorattribute(v=vs.110).aspx) and [`InstanceContextMode`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.servicebehaviorattribute.instancecontextmode(v=vs.110).aspx).

> Use the InstanceContextMode property to specify when new service
>   objects are created. Because the service object is not directly
>   connected to the communicating channel, the lifetime of the service
>   objects is independent of the lifetime of the channel between a client
>   and the service application. The default value, PerSession, instructs
>   the service application to create a new service object when a new
>   communication session is established between a client and the service
>   application. Subsequent calls in the same session are handled by the
>   same object.

In your example the following actions occur:

- User calls `checkTemperature` method of WCF service.
- New channel and new session creates on the Server.
- New instance of `SmartRoom` class instantiated. When SmartRoom
  constructed it also creates a new instance of `SmartRoomClass` class
  because class initialize its instance fields and propertis (line
  `SmartRoomClass sr = new SmartRoomClass();` executed).
- Method `checkTemperature` actually called on the server. It calls
  `SmartRoomClass.CheckTemperature1(...)` method that changes
  `TemperaturaZrak` value.
- The method execution ends and your client app ends the session (or
  just don't store it).
- User calls `getAirTemperature` method of WCF service.
- New channel and new session creates on the Server.
- **New instance of** `SmartRoom` **class instantiated. When SmartRoom constructed it also creates a new instance of** `SmartRoomClass`
  **class with new value of** `TemperaturaZrak`**!**
- Method `getAirTemperature` actually called on the server. It returns
  value 15 because new instance `SmartRoomClass` initialized with that
  value.

Now you know why the default temperature was returned from `getAirTemperature` method.

How to fix this behavior to your needs? First you can store wcf service client instance from call to call like in [this example](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/86007/ways-to-do-WCF-instance-management-Per-call-Per#How%20to%20implement%20per%20session%20Instancing).

But opened channel is not always a good idea because it takes extra resources of the server. The better way is to change your `SmartRoomClass` and store `TemperaturaZrak` value not only in the memory but in the data storage that can also save different values per users or on the other way. The easiest way is to use file or [Isolated Storage](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xf96a1wz(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: Thank you so much! I understand the problem now. I'll check this isolated storage, sounds good enought. I'll write here if i need more help.

Comment: @Ales there are many different realizations, techniques and technologies for storing data on the server and there is no 1 right answer what to use. Isolated storage is just one of the simple solutions but it'll be better to choose based on business requirements and scenarios. For example, isolated storage is not portable from server to server and you'll need to write your own migration. Also, you may want to store more data per each user and need to use relational model or other options. Good luck.

Comment: At the moment I solved my problem. All I needed to do is to put "static" before ´SmartRoomClass sr = new SmartRoomClass();´. I dont know...it did some magic.

Comment: No it is not. Static fields stored in the class not in the instance. Then you have the same instance of `SmartRoomClass` each call because this line called just one time. You will have the same result if you add `[ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.Single)]` before `SmartyRoom` service. It's not good design and can cause problems (for example, you can't save Temperature value when server stops and separate it by users) then I missed this solution but referenced it as first solution (by link).